# getting posts from other site network in wordpress 3.0

Tags: wordpress

i have set up the new wordpress 3.0 with multisite network capabilities. What i want to do is get and show blogs from other network site in the main blog. Like if i have set up the blog at example.com and i have other network sites at articles.example.com, movies.example.com. I want to get the posts from the articles.example.com and movies.example.com to show up in the main site at example.com. Is there any parameter in query_post to get the post from different network sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a swith blog function which can be used or this purpose.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog supposed to be a bit buggy. Tentative docs will come out in 3.2: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/14953/ALT%20switch_to_blog%20and%20restore_current_blog%20inline%20docs.diff